# k6 redis client doesn't connect to Azure Cache for Redis

Tags: redis, client, performance-testing, load-testing, k6

When I setup the k6 redis client to connect to an azure Redis instance in the cloud, I get this error:

`ERRO[0001] Uncaught (in promise) i/o timeout`

Here is the client setup code:

`const redisClient = new redis.Client({ addrs: new Array("myredis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380"), password: "primary_access_key_here" });`

The moment it tries to "set" or "get" with the redis client, it immediately returns that "i/o timeout" error.

It does work, however, when I run a local Redis server and then point the client to localhost:

`const redisClient = new redis.Client({ addrs: new Array("localhost"), password: "" });`

Any ideas?  Is there some bug in the k6 client that doesn't allow it to work with Azure Cache for Redis?

I tried setting the address value to a current Redis instance with the correct primary key for the password.  It works when I set it to localhost with an empty password, however.

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshooting and trial & error, it turns out that the issue here is that the Azure Redis server was set to only accept SSL requests.  When I allow for non-ssl connections, I can connect to it directly.  The problem is really with the k6 redis client in that it only uses insecure tcp to connect to the redis server instance.  So, the resolution is to simply wait for K6 to update their client to allow for SSL connections since we want to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.